# JavaFX 2 - JPedal included in a Pane

Tags: java, javafx-2, hbox, pane, jpedal

Is it possible to include a JPedal PDF Viewer in a HBox JavaFX Application, with other stuffs added to the following slots of the HBox? Any tips?

Comment: could be a solution, i'll try! Do you have any link to examples for that? I mean example where the Jpedal is already used inside a WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if it's possible to put JPedal inside JavaFX - there's no official mechanism for putting Swing inside JavaFX, but you may be able to find some hacks online. Perhaps this functionality will arrive in JavaFX8 or 9.

Regardless, it's a possibility that in the future JPedal will include a JavaFXDisplay if there's a demand for it and it's commercially viable.

We do lots of playing with JavaFX - we currently have an online converter to demo PDF to JavaFX and PDF to FXML functionality: http://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-javafx-fxml-converter/

Recently we announced that we have swapped out Java3D for JavaFX in the PageFlow mode inside JPedal's Viewer: http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/01/announcing-the-pageflow-pdf-viewer-mode-in-javafx/

There's a video of it in action here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auwNrIPt0Tc

And as already pointed out, there's section on the website with some extra bits like JPedalFX which is a lightweight JavaFX PDF viewer. There's also PDF to JavaFX functionality in the plugins for Eclipse, NetBeans and IDEA.
We hope to update the JavaFX section in the near future with what we have been working on recently too: http://www.idrsolutions.com/javafx/

Answer (score 0):

JPedal already supports JavaFX, pretty cool actually.

http://www.idrsolutions.com/javafx/

Comment: We have released a free JavaFX plugin and written a tutorial to show how to integrate it into NetBeans plugin (which will also work for standalone Apps) at http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/01/writing-javafx-pdf-viewer-plugin-netbeans-1-introduction/